# Does $\omega$-consistency depend on the encoding?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, model-theory, foundations

A given theory $T$ can interpret the language of arithmetic in different ways, and therefore it seems to me like it is possible that in one of these ways $T$ would be $\omega$-consistent but not in the other.

Assuming PA is $\omega$-consistent, there seems to be an easy way to construct such a theory: Let $T$ have two sorts and put the axioms of PA (Peano Arithmetic) for one of the sorts and PA+not(Con(PA)) for the other. Then depending on which sort we use to interpret arithmetic we would either get something $\omega$-consistent or not.

Is this correct? If so, $\omega$-consistency seems like an ill-defined concept. How do we deal with this issue? A similar question can arise if we have some model of some theory and want to know whether $Con(T)$ for some $T$ is true for that model, as the answer depends on the encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great question! In general, "reasonably strong" theories will always have *distinguished implementations* (the jargon is actually **interpretations**, but meh) of the natural numbers, and it is with respect to these that we make sense of things like $\omega$-consistency.

Let's look at $\mathsf{ZFC}$ for concreteness. We can prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there is a **smallest model** of (say) Robinson's arithmetic $\mathsf{Q}$. (Here "smallest" is meant in terms of initial segment embeddability.) In particular, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $\mathbb{N}^\mathcal{M}$ is the finite ordinals of $\mathcal{M}$ construed as a model of arithmetic in the usual way, and $X$ is some other "implementation" of a model of $\mathsf{Q}$ inside $\mathcal{M}$, we have **in $\mathcal{M}$** that there is a unique initial segment embedding $\mathbb{N}^\mathcal{M}\rightarrow X$. Moreover, we have - again $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably - that any two such implementations are isomorphic.

So there is a very precise sense in which the "obvious" way of implementing the naturals inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is the best possible.

Comment: So, maybe a more "categorical" way to think about this would be to say that these notions are relative to a pair $(T, I)$ where $T$ is a theory and $I$ is an implementation of the natural numbers on $T$, right?

Comment: @Carla_ Well, but there is (up to unique isomorphism in a precise sense) a **best** implementation of the naturals in $T$. So you can relativize to any other, but I don't know of any time you actually want to (and certainly that's not what's meant by e.g. "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\omega$-consistent").

Comment: you mean in "nice enough" $T$? In the example $T$ i gave in my question there doesn't seem to be a best one.

Comment: @Carla_ Yes, we need $T$ to be "nice enough" (and we don't, as far as I'm aware, ever talk about non-nice-enough theories being $\omega$-consistent).